# React Native Display Rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I updated the code to reflect Denis' solution. However, react is now no longer responding to commands sent from the node server

```
export default class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        ren: "",
        action: "background",
        media: "white",
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        uri: "https://www.tomswallpapers.com/pic/201503/720x1280/tomswallpapers.com-17932.jpg"
      };
  }

  componentDidMount(){ 
    this.startSocketIO();
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    socket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT);
  }

  startSocketIO(){
    socket.on('function_received', func_var => {
        let command = func_var.split(" ");
        this.setState({action: command[0]});
        this.setState({media: command[1]});
        console.log(this.state.action);
        console.log(this.state.media);
        switch(this.state.action){
          case 'image':
            this.setState({ uri: this.state.media});
            console.log(this.state.uri);
          case 'background':
            this.setState({ backgroundColor: this.state.media});
            console.log(this.state.backgroundColor);
          default:
            console.log(this.state.backgroundColor);
            // return (<View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, flex: 1}} />);
        }
      });
  }
  render(){
      return (
        null
      );
  }
```

## }

I'm currently working on a basic react native app that displays images received in uri format from a node server and changes the background color. Separately, both of my implementations work. (See the BackGround and ImageServer components) I'm now attempting to combine the functionality of both components into one component named display. So far my current code looks like it should work without issue however after sending a command to the device via socket.io it appears that the render doesn't go any further since my console logs stop populating after a test. I'm not sure if there is an issue with the setup of the switch statement or if I'm somehow causing a race condition. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image, Text, StyleSheet, Button, View, Dimensions, Vibration} from 'react-native';

const io = require('socket.io-client');
//change this to your public ip "google what is my ip address"
//This will be modified in the future to grab the ip address being used by
//the node server
let server = 'redacted';
let socket = io(server, {
  transports: ['websocket']
});

export default class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        action: "background",
        media: "white",
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        uri: "https://www.tomswallpapers.com/pic/201503/720x1280/tomswallpapers.com-17932.jpg"
      };
  }
  render(){
      socket.on('function_received', func_var => {
        var command = func_var.split(" ");
        this.setState({action: command[0]});
        this.setState({media: command[1]});
      });
      console.log(this.state.action);
      console.log(this.state.media);
      switch(this.state.action){
        case 'image':
          this.setState({ uri: this.state.media});
          return (
            <Image 
              source={{uri: this.state.uri}} 
              style={styles.fullscreen} />
            );
        case 'background':
          this.setState({ backgroundColor: this.state.media});
          return (<View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, flex: 1}} />);
        default:
          return (<View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, flex: 1}} />);
      }
  }
}


export class BackGround extends Component {
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
      }; 
  }
    render(){
        socket.on('function_received', func_var => {
        this.setState({ backgroundColor: func_var});
        });
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, flex: 1}} />
        );
    }
}
export class ImageServer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        uri: "https://www.tomswallpapers.com/pic/201503/720x1280/tomswallpapers.com-17932.jpg"
        };
  }
    render() {
    socket.on('function_received', func_var => {
      //Vibration.vibrate([0, 500, 200, 500,200,500,200,500,200,500,200,500,200], false);
      this.setState({ uri: func_var});
    });
    return(
        <Image 
        source={{uri: this.state.uri}} 
        style={styles.fullscreen}
      />
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Never call `setState` inside render function. That is causing the infinite loop in this code.

Comment: Where should i be calling it then? should i move socket into the constructor?

Comment: You have a socket.io listener, create a method and call it from componentWillMount(), after that call this.setState({key: image}) and update your component state - this is a best way for you in this case

Comment: Also in my opinion you need to add shouldComponentUpdate() and check image on uniqueness

Comment: `this.setState({ uri: this.state.media});` and `this.setState({ backgroundColor: this.state.media});` are the culprits here. I dont see any need of them either in render.

Answer (score 0):

You code should like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.startSocketIO();
}

startSocketIO() {
  socket.on('some_method', (response) => {
    this.setState({ key: response.some_value })
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  // unsubscribe socket.io here !important
}

render() {
  return (
    // JSX
  );
}
```

Comment: componentWillUnmount(){
    socket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT);
  }

is this correct for the unmount?

Comment: I think yes, check network requests or put console.log into startSocketIO for checking